# How to export Node.js and express Project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, node.js, eclipse-plugin, express

I have some Node.js project using express frame work I am migrating to node eclipse, so I have to import some projects to eclipse.Can any one please suggest how to import express projects to Node Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

To import Node.js project into Eclipse
Since [Nodeclipse](http://www.nodeclipse.org/) 0.3.1 use File -> New Node Project and specify location of your existing project.
It will add just `.project` file. Yes, it is implemented not as would be expected.

Or just copy `.project` file to your existing project, change project name inside, and then File -> Import -> Existing Project into Workplace. (That however does not add settings like JSHint and JSDT configuration)

Check also built-in help or see it online https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/org.nodeclipse.help/contents#intro

UPDATE: recommended is to run `nodeclipse -p` CLI tool. (Install with `npm i -g nodeclipse`)

Answer (score 0):

[Nodeclipse](http://www.nodeclipse.org/) just adds *IDE* support for node js into eclipse. Since node js and express files are just javascript files that can be open in any text editor there is no migration. You just open the node js project in eclipse that's it.

Comment: Some configuration for JSHint and JSDT is needed.